# How to use URI-names for SQLite PDO

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

In C sqlite can handle [URI filenames](http://www.sqlite.org/uri.html) like

```
rc = sqlite3_open("file:memdb1?mode=memory&cache=shared", &db);
```

which opens [e.g.](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html#urifilenameexamples) the way to [shared in-memory databases](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html).

Is there a way to do this with PDO?